# In Google Patents, how can a priority date be more than one year before a non-provisional patent application filing date?

Tags: google-patents, priority-date

In Google Patents, how can a priority date be more than one year before a non-provisional patent application filing date?  My understanding was that you have to file a non-provisional patent application within 12 months of a public disclosure to retain patent rights.